# highchart axis position with negative values

Tags: highcharts

In the stacked bar shown below

[image]

the negative values are represented with the reference line on top, this seems to be redundant with the original axis present below, is there a way to actually show only one axis in the place of 0 marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a parameter opposite as true.

```
xAxis:{
        opposite:true
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2s85hcbu/

You can also disable gridlines on yAxis

```
yAxis:{
        gridLineWidth:0
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2s85hcbu/1/